# Eddystone beacon security if not using an app (just based on beacon URL)

Tags: eddystone

I am doing research on an Eddystone project where the user would receive personal (and therefore to some extent confidential) information based on an Eddystone URL on their phones. There is no app involved, so the user would be directed to a webpage (based on the eddystone URL) which will display the info.

I am wondering regarding the security implications of this: Without an app, I guess the EID cannot be used - is this right (or is the EID accessible in the notification and can be passed to the destination website as a parameter)? Therefore, I suppose anyone with the name of the url could then access this information which would become a problem as you could scrap the data for every user using the service with a simple script that reads this website every now and then.

There may be a way around it if the url in the beacon can be changed on the fly to something like www.abc.com/some-random-number. That would work but it would mean that the beacon url must be updated frequently.

Does anyone know of any beacons that come with an API that would allow me to do this from a Windows machine (I know manufacturers have apps that can change beacon data but that is not an option because this should run without user intervention)? E.g. I was thinking of a USB beacon that can be accessed from a little piece of software on windows which changes the url.

Or does anyone have a better idea on how to deal with this?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to show the website visitors some personal and confidential information, I do think the only way to go about is to have some sort of login on the website. The ability to change randomly the URL address that the beacon broadcasts would not be helpful, as you need a way to connect the random website address to the individual accessing it. The EID is a way to distinguish which apps can receive specific beacon information - it does not check which individual is using the application. (And you can only utilize it with applications, at least for now).